# Keep information in array when using a form multiple times

Tags: arrays, vba, userform

I have a form in which, every time a button is clicked, an array is filled in with the information of a textbox.

How can I keep the elements in the array and not have it empty every time I use the form?
This is the code I wrote:

```
Dim myArray() As String

Sub button_Click()
    
    If Len(Join(myArray)) = 0 Then
        k = 0
    Else
        k = UBound(myArray)
    End If

    ReDim Preserve myArray(k To k + 1)
    myArray(k) = "Number " & k

End Sub
```

Comment: Declare the array **in a standard module**: `Public myArray() As String`, if you need to use it from different places (modules)...  Or declare it as `Static` inside the sub, if you need it only for that specific Sub. And, of course, delete/comment the declaration from the form. But, before that, can you explain **in words** what you try accomplishing? At the first glance it looks that an error will be raised when run the code second time... Do you want incrementing the numeric part after each click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what @FaneDuru recommended.
I declared in a standard module `Public myArray() As String` and this is the generic code that will be inside the form below, which also had erros:

```
Dim k As Integer

Private Sub butt_add_Click()

    If Len(Join(myArray)) = 0 Then
        k = 0
        ReDim myArray(0)
        myArray(k) = textBox.Value
    Else
        k = UBound(myArray) + 1
        ReDim Preserve myArray(k)
        myArray(k) = textBox.Value
    End If
    
    Sheets("Prueba").Cells(k + 1, 1) = myArray(k)
```

[image]

All in all, you can store the information of a text box in an array, which increments the number of elements as many times as the button is pressed.

The last line of the code is just for checking everything works properly.

Comment: The code you show is different from the one shown in the question... Why `ReDim Preserve myArray(0)`, if the array is empty? Try only `ReDim myArray(0)`, since is nothing to be preserved. If you do not increment anything and your purpose is to keep all text box values, why `ReDim Preserve myArray(k - 1 To k)` and not simple `ReDim Preserve myArray( k)`? If you do  not have a huge range of such values and want keeping the values **even for the next time when you open the workbook, or to be used from another workbook**, you can join the array content and save it in `Registry`...

Comment: The code is different because, as I said, the one shown in the questions was wrong.You were right about the use of ReDim. I didn't know it was used like this. I am modifying the answer.